# Match all strings between brackets and with an uppercase

Tags: regex

I want to match [abcDe] but not [abcde]. I used `(?=\[([^\[\]]*)\])` to match all between brackets, but then I tried `[A-Z]+(?=\[([^\[\]]*)\])` to only match between brackets when it contains an uppercase and it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use

```
\[[^][A-Z]*[A-Z][^][]*]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[` Match the opening square bracket
- `[^][A-Z]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except `[` `]` or an uppercase char
- `[A-Z]` Match a single uppercase char
- `[^][]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except `[` `]`
- `]` Match the closing square bracket

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/287vd7/1)

Comment: Thanks, this works fine in regex101 for example, but when I try to make a SQL 8.0.18 request like 
select * from procedures where template REGEXP '\[[^][A-Z]*[A-Z][^][]*]'
I get the following error : "(3696): The regular expression contains an unclosed bracket expression."

Comment: @sol You can excape the square brackets inside the character class `\[[^\]\[A-Z]*[A-Z][^\]\[]*\]`

Comment: I tried this but I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @sol In that case I think you have to double escape them `\\[[^\\]\\[A-Z]*[A-Z][^\\]\\[]*\\]`

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the regex flavor but this could work:

```
(?<=\[)[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?=\])
```

- `(?<=\[)` - behind me is an opening bracket
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - allow upper or lower case chars
- `[A-Z]` - require one uppercase char
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - allow upper or lower case chars
- `(?=\])` - ahead of me is a closing bracket

https://regex101.com/r/iz5Dtl/1